# In Microsoft SQL Server, how to split rows using datetime data

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I am working on a project for my university, I am supposed to create a dashboard for machines downtime.

Every time that a machine is down during the day, the availability is calculated as [ 24 (hours) - Downtime / 24 (hours) ].

However, there are some situations where the machines are down more than 1 day, so it means that I have the split the number of hours that machine is down and distributed to the respective days.

Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

Here is what the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could you change the date format to [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)?

Comment: Please see edited answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea,

Create one temp table with number between specific range by `SELECT DISTINCT SeqDateDiff = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 1000`.

**PS:** *the range is 0 to 1000 in the sample, you can create wider range, but it should not be neccessary, you can consider remove the machine if already down over 1000 days. And there are some other methods to create this kind of range table, you can google it.*

Then left join with your table with date difference by `on target.DateDiff+1>seq.SeqDateDiff`.

Then the rest is simple, just calculate out reported/completed based on different situations.

[Check working sample at SQL fiddler](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/642e4/3).

Below is the codes:

```
select ServiceID, 
    case when SeqDateDiff>0 then cast(DATEADD(day, SeqDateDiff, Reported) As Date) else Reported end Started, 
    case when SeqDateDiff=DateDiff 
        then Completed 
        else DATEADD(second, -1, cast(cast(DATEADD(day, SeqDateDiff+1, Reported) As Date) as DateTime)) 
    end Completed,
DateDiff, SeqDateDiff
from (select ServiceID, Completed, Reported, DATEDIFF(day, Reported, Completed) DateDiff from YourTable) target
left join (
SELECT DISTINCT SeqDateDiff = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
) seq on target.DateDiff+1>seq.SeqDateDiff
```

Comment: Hi, so if my table is a query, where should I put it into your code? Thank you!

Comment: @Felix replace `(select ServiceID, Completed, Reported, DATEDIFF(day, Reported, Completed) DateDiff from YourTable) target` with your query, but you need to adjust alias for related columns to match Completed, Reported, DateDiff

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you mind explaining a bit about the seqdatediff here? What does it do? I still quite dont get it yet.

Comment: `(
SELECT DISTINCT SeqDateDiff = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
) seq` will return 1000 rows with 1 columns=SeqDateDiff, if Completed-Reported=1, that means we need to add one row. so use `left join on DateDiff+1>seq.SeqDateDiff` to expand the rows. Check this to see [how join works](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I have got a hang of it already. However, after I execute the code, there is 1 problem. For example: machine A started at 2/9 01:50 and ended at 2/16 08:40. so calculating the SeqDateDiff, it should give me 7 days. Yet your code actually gives me SeqDateDiff up to 175. I wonder if there is anything wrong?

Comment: @Felix did you check the fiddle? i believe it will return seven rows. I doubt the issue is probably caused by your date format.

Comment: sorry I have figured it out why. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when datediff(hh, reported, completed)>12 then 12 else 
datediff(hh, reported, completed) end from yourtable
if day(reported)<>day(completed)
begin
select datediff(hh, cast(completed as date), completed)  from yourtable 
end
```

Assuming it's never down more than 2 days.  If so, adjust logic accordingly...

Comment: he wants one more row for machine B and not calculate the downtime hours into days and hours. see expected result (3rows vs 2 orig rows)

Comment: Hi, so if my table is a sql query, where should I put it in your query?

Comment: @Daniel: Hi, I have already tried this and it says that "SQL Error (156): Incorrect syntax near keyword 'IF' Incorrect syntax near keyword 'END'" although I just only substitute 'yourtable' with my query. Nothing else!